# Light on when should not

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

We replaced our light fittings to ceiling fans with LED lights remote controlled, so the switch is always on but the remote controls the light and fans.

There is a problem on the top floor where 3 out of 4 lights emit a bit of light when should be off (switch is on). When the switch is off there is no light. I've also noticed that when a light is turned on in a different room the light lights up for a second when the switch is off. All 3 fans were replaced with no help. Any idea what the problem could be?

The light cannot be replaced on the fan, the LEDs are integrated. The downstairs fans (2) are ok.

Comment: Is the remote system one that came with the fan, or one that came separately?

Comment: Fan model number?

Comment: Ok, so the remote is not turning the light all the way off.  What happens if you replace one of the lights with incandescent? Are these leds rated to work with dimmers?

Comment: the remote and the fan were bought together from the same provider. I am in Australia the fan mpdel is moonah 52 led fan. The led is integrated into the fan and cannot be removed. Not sure about the rating but should only be on and off